# Como definir apenas um parametro não default para uma função?

Tags: javascript, funções

Eu me deparei com um problema em javascript que em python seria simples de solucionar, apenas dizendo que o parâmetro se refere a 'text'.

- create_element (text = `A média dos valores cadastrados é ${media_lista}.`)

Porém em Javascript, ele lê o texto no parâmetro como 'elem', por ser o primeiro parâmetro requisitado e SIMPLESMENTE IGNORA o 'text='.

Eu sei que uma das soluções é colocar 'text' como o primeiro parâmetro a ser passado, mas não é a solução que eu procuro.

```
function create_element(elem='p', text, parent='result_box') {
    let item = document.createElement(elem);
    item.text = text;
    parent.appendChild(item);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript não possui passagem de parâmetros por nome. Geralmente quando uma função precisa receber vários argumentos, é normal enviar um objeto, com as propriedades representando os parâmetros.

Com desestruturação, você pode chegar a um resultado parecido, embora não tão bonito com a seguinte sintaxe:

```
function create_element({elem='p', text, parent='result_box'} = {}) {
    let item = document.createElement(elem);
    item.text = text;
    parent.appendChild(item);
};
```

Dessa forma você pode invocar a função sem passar parâmetros:

```
create_element()
```

Ou passando um objeto com as propriedades representando os parâmetros:

```
create_element({text: 'Olá Mundo'})         // apenas text
create_element({parent: 'root'})            // apenas parent
create_element({text: 'teste', elem: 'td'}) // a ordem não importa
```